# Django ModelForm RadioSelect Set Value or ID

Tags: python, django, modelform

I want to set the value of the RadioSelect field in my modelform:

```
class Redeem_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(max_value=10, min_value=1, label=_('quantity'), initial=1, error_messages={'invalid':'This value must be between 1 and 10'})
    class Meta:
        model = Reward
    fields = ['reward_denomination']
        widgets = {'reward_denomination': forms.RadioSelect}
```

Right now, the generated code looks like this:

```
<input name="reward_denomination" type="radio" id="gift-card_0" value=1>
    <label for="gift-card_0">$5 Gift Card</label>

<input name="reward_denomination" type="radio" id="gift-card_1" value=2>
    <label for="gift-card_1">$10 Gift Card</label>

<input name="reward_denomination" type="radio" id="gift-card_2" value=3>
    <label for="gift-card_2">$20 Gift Card</label>
```

The values as they are are pretty much useless. My reward_denomination model has a slug field that would be perfect for the value (or better yet, as the id), but I'm unsure as to how I would set that myself. Any help?

Comment: Are you trying to change the `value` attribute of the `input` elements, or the text of the `label` elements? If it's the `value`, what's the motivation? That's a value that's not directly displayed to the user and is intended for use by the widget in looking up the selected instances.

Comment: @Peter DeGlopper Well, ideally I would want to change the id value to be the slug of the gift card. I want each button to be accessible by something I write in Jquery/Ajax. If I can somehow access the slug of the denomination, it would make object lookup and Ajax calls simpler (I'd imagine, anyway).

Comment: Ah - normally you can manually set the `id` for a field's widget using `attrs`. I need to check how that works with a `RadioSelect` since it renders multiple elements.

Comment: Also, which version are you on?

Comment: After some checking - you could easily set the base `id` value for the set of buttons, to which Django will automatically append `_0`, `_1`, etc. Since you want to override the `id` value for each choice in the select, you will have to define a custom widget class. Fortunately, you won't have to override much besides the class that renders each radio button, but the exact details of that vary by version. 1.4 to current is pretty stable, before that it's pretty different.

Comment: @Peter DeGlopper I'm on Django 1.6. I"m going to look into what you said about custom widgets, thanks